# I am not able to get any response from ST25RU3993 via arduino SPI

Tags: arduino, spi, embedded, rfid

I ran out of clues of what could be stopping me from driving the ST25RU3993, hopefully I can get some useful directions from here...

I am trying to drive the ST25RU3993 Eval board using SPI, with my Arduino Due (i read an earlier post on that ran at different voltage and solve using 3V arduino board, in my case both devices run on 3.3V) to prototype a quick project. I used the oscilloscope to probe and it seems my spi outputs (sclk, mosi, chipselect, enable) are looking good. However my ST25 board is not responding at all.

Here is a picture of the eval board and here is the link to the data sheet for both evaluation board and the IC: [ST25RU3993 IC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st25ru3993.pdf) , [ST25RU3993 Eval](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group0/f0/c1/b1/de/ff/49/4b/23/DM00473660/files/DM00473660.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00473660.pdf)
[image]

my connection from the Arduino Due board is simple SPI connection: MISO to MISO, MOSI to MOSI, CLK to CLK, an output pin(52) as chip-select, an output pin(2) as enable. The eval-board is powered 3.3V via arduino. Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
////////////////////////////////////////////
//set up pins for arudino due
//MOSI:ICSP-4
//MISO:ICSP-1
//SCK:ICSP-3
//NCS:52
//EN:2
//IRQ:22
///////////////////////////////////////////////


const int NCS = 52;
const int EN = 2;
const int IRQ = 7;

//SPI setting
SPISettings settingsA(500000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);

void setup() {

  pinMode (NCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IRQ, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(EN, HIGH);//set enable to high


  Serial.begin(9600);

  SPI.begin();
  SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA); //I wrote to the following 2 main control registers, register description is at the data sheet

  digitalWrite (NCS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0b00000000); // write and register addressL: Device staus register
  SPI.transfer(0b00000001); // value for this register: Turn RF-On
  digitalWrite (NCS, HIGH);

  digitalWrite (NCS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0b00000001); // write and register addressL: Protocal Selection Register
  SPI.transfer(0b00000000); // value for this register: Choose EPC Gen2
  digitalWrite (NCS, HIGH);
  Serial.print("written");

  SPI.endTransaction();
}


int8_t O;
void loop() {

  for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {

    SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA); //read from my RSSI_Display register
    digitalWrite (NCS, LOW);

    O =   SPI.transfer16(0b0110101100000000);

    digitalWrite (NCS, HIGH);

  }
  Serial.print(O, DEC);
}
```

I had tried multiple clock rates from 100k to 5M and all SPI modes.

Usually with these kind of simple code I can drive many sensors via SPI but the ST25 RFID is giving me a very hard time. I asked around in ST community and someone ask if I had connected my IRQ. I did but I don't know why IRQ is important in master if all I am looking for right now is simple to turn the chip on and get some kind of response back.

Any one has a clue? or it is just a bad idea to drive the device with Arduino?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably make sure to hold the eval board's on-board STM32L4 micro in reset while you try to communicate with the ST25 to ensure that it doesn't conflict. Pull P3-pin10 down to ground.

Comment: Holding the pin down doesn't change my output. What was my pin 10 on Arduino wasn't connected to anything, Pin 7 you mean perhaps?

Comment: P3-Pin-10 on the Eval board. Not the Arduino.

Comment: YES! able to get different response out of different register after pulling down P3-pin10. Thank you brhans for pointing it out!